# How to separate two stuck filters

Tags: filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a stuck screw filter off of my lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/how-do-i-get-a-stuck-screw-filter-off-of-my-lens)

What are the best techniques for separating two filters that are stuck together (In my case a polarizer and a UV filter)?

Comment: Duplicate?  http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13627/269

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me too